# PlayerPrefs in unity does not work properly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game for Android in Unity 5.6.3f1 and have a problem with `PlayerPrefs`.

This is my code:

```
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Key1);
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Key2);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
```

After this block of code, when I check in the new scene, Key1 is deleted but Key2 still exists.

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that loading a new scene will end up calling `Awake` and `Start` on every component in that scene, which can invite a lot of side effects if you're not careful about it. Are you absolutely sure that nothing in that scene could be re-initializing your player prefs such as `Key2`?

Comment: yes i'm sure, my code is fine and i don't know why Key2 is still exist

Comment: Sorry the problem is very likely on your side. You need to show more code. 1.What is the value of key1 and key2? 2.How do you do know that key2 is not deleted? 3.Where do you call those function from? If you can't answer these 3 questions then it will be hard to really help you.

Comment: @AmRzA If you're confident that a bug exists in Unity, please provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the bug exists. Based on what you've posted so far, I'm confident the issue is based on interactions between your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The DeleteKey method takes a string as input, you seem to be passing a variable.

Maybe the issue is the value you're passing as Key2 does not match the value you are passing to the corresponding PlayerPrefs.Set* method

Try debuggind the input and output and make sure the strings match

Comment: no i'm sure about that, both of them are const static string

Comment: When you load the new scene aren't you re-adding key2 somewhere?
Maybe try putting a breakpoint on the following line:

SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

Then check your playerprefs and see if Key2 was removed. It should be removed. Then continue execution and if it is re-added, it's because the issue is somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 0):

try with ""    -

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PrefsTest", test); PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("PrefsTest");
```